# Windows app javascript access to files in a folder in "futureAccessList"

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-phone-8

Using Windows 8 API it is possible to write an app that accesses a file under the app directory, for example like this:

```
audio.src = "jazz.mp3"
```

It is also possible to add a folder to a "futureAccessList" which is basically a list of folder the app has access permissions for:

```
Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.futureAccessList.addOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder);
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
audio.src = "C:\\myMusicFolder\\jazz.mp3"
audio.src = "F:\\anotherFolder\\blues.mp3"
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to let the user pick the folders "C:\myMusicFolder" and "F:\anotherFolder".
You can then add these folders to the `FutureAccessList`.

If you want to access these files now, you need to iterate through the folders in your `FutureAccessList` and check if that's the folder you are looking for (i.e. C:\myMusicFolder).
An efficient way to do that would be to store the path of the folder as `MetaData`.
You can then retrieve the StorageFolder object from the `FutureAccessList` and use it to retrieve the mp3 file.